# Null pointer exception listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been searching for a solution to this and just can't seem to find anything that works,
It's a simple listview with a icon and text, hopefully I've just overlooked something stupid but I would appreciate it if someone could take a look. :)

Here is my java: StorePick.java

```
package com.ctc.android.widget;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  

public class StorePick extends Activity {

String[] data={"Morningside","Primross"};
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.storepick);


lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview_layout,R.id.txtView1,data);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

my xml: storepick.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

my listview layout: listview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/bpicon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Here is my stack trace

```
10-23 10:09:12.916: W/dalvikvm(31213): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4180ada0)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213): Process: com.ctc.android.widget, PID: 31213
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:392)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2765)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2532)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2262)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-23 10:09:12.926: E/AndroidRuntime(31213):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the answer posted by Pedro Oliveira answered your question, please accept it by clicking on the green check mark on the left of his post. doing This rewards his effort in answering your question and informs the other users that this question is already answered. You can go to the [quick 2 minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) so that you can learn the ropes of this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:id="@+id/textView1"` it's different from `R.id.txtView1`

Change your adapter to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listview_layout,R.id.textView1,data);
```

Comment: thanx man! I can't believe i didn't see that work's perfectly now

Comment: @StefanGrobler No problem. Remember to mark the this as solution and have a nice day :)